# Why did I lose my "acceptance"?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

[Two](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15643/source-for-the-minhag-of-gebrokts) [questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7247/chabad-custom-of-not-allowing-water-to-touch-matzah-on-pesach) were merged. Both had accepted answers.

Why did I lose my "acceptance" over the other? Both users weren't around for some time?

Comment: I *think* the accepted answer on the merged-*to* question remains accepted. In this case, I merged to the older question, as I tend to do if the amount of work merging in either direction would be about equal and the questions are about of equal quality.